# Draw custom background shapes for tooltips in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been asked to make use of highcharts/stackcharts for a project I’m working on. Our Artist designed a look and feel that matches other components that we are making use of. I need to change the shape and size of the tooltips and the handles on the navigator. Basicly I need to skin the charts.

I can’t use another charting library at this stage as we already committed to highchars but if this isn’t possible, then that would be a deal breaker for us.

The Stackcharts documentation states this:

> handles: Object
> Options for the handles for dragging the zoomed area. Available options are backgroundColor and borderColor.

This is not good enough :(

I also tried drawing a custom tooltip with this code:

```
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var st = '<div style="background-color:#ff8000"><svg version="1.1" width="55" height="55"><path d="m 27.7 3.9 C 13.5 3.9 1.9 15.4 1.9 29.6 C 1.9 43.8 13.5 55.3 27.7 55.3 C 41.9 55.3 53.4 43.8 53.4 29.6 C 53.4 15.4 41.9 3.9 27.7 3.9 Z M 21.8 14.8 C 22 14.7 22.2 14.8 22.3 14.8 C 23.8 15.3 24.2 18 23.2 20.9 C 22.3 23.9 20.4 25.9 19 25.5 C 17.5 25 17.2 22.3 18.1 19.3 C 18.9 16.7 20.5 14.9 21.8 14.8 Z M 29.7 14.9 C 31.6 14.9 33.9 17.1 35.2 20.3 C 36.8 23.9 36.5 27.5 34.6 28.4 C 32.7 29.2 29.8 26.9 28.3 23.2 C 26.7 19.6 27 16 28.9 15.1 C 29.2 15 29.5 15 29.7 14.9 Z M 49.3 28 L 48.6 29.4 C 44.2 37.2 38 43.8 31.3 46.3 C 27.9 47.5 24.5 47.7 21.1 46.5 C 17.8 45.2 14.6 42.6 11.7 38.2 L 11.2 37.3 L 12.2 37.4 C 31.3 39.8 38.2 33.4 47.9 28.7 L 49.3 28z" fill="#ffdd55" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="0"></path></svn></div>';
                return st;
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdDk4/

But the svg gets drawn into the border and it’s doesn’t seem like I can replace it without hacking it :(

I don’t want to do that.

I have investigated and goggle’d for hours without any success. Is there anyone who knows how I can accomplish this?

Please Sir, can I some morrr customisation?

Answer (score 1):

In case when you set useHTML as true, then you can set background in CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdDk4/5/

```
 formatter: function () {
                var st = '<div class="tooltip">'+this.y+'</div>';
                return st;
            }
```

CSS:

```
    .tooltip {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url('http://aeseda.psu.edu/wp-content/themes/theme-mingle/assets/images/placeholder.jpg');
}
```

I advice to not use SVG in this way, because in IE<8 tooltip will not appear, because older browseres uses VML.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution doesn't really give me morrr than what I already had. I can easily add a background image to the div I had but there is a reason I need the SVG and not just a bitmap for the background. I’m using raphaeljs to draw the SVG paths so in IE the paths will be drawn as VML.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to point out is that I needed to draw a custom shape as a background. The correct solution is to use something like raphaeljs or something similar to draw the custom shapes.

For the sake of simplicity, I have updated the fiddle to reflect the solution I was after. It’s not that much different than my original code but I must have been intoxicated when first asked the question. Here is the update fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdDk4/

With this you can draw custom shapes as backgrounds to your tooltips. Remember, this won’t work in IE8 but you can use something like raphaeljs to convert the SVG shapes to VML.

```
 formatter: function () {
    var st = '<svg version="1.1" width="55" height="55"><path d="m 27.7 3.9 C 13.5 3.9 1.9 15.4 1.9 29.6 C 1.9 43.8 13.5 55.3 27.7 55.3 C 41.9 55.3 53.4 43.8 53.4 29.6 C 53.4 15.4 41.9 3.9 27.7 3.9 Z M 21.8 14.8 C 22 14.7 22.2 14.8 22.3 14.8 C 23.8 15.3 24.2 18 23.2 20.9 C 22.3 23.9 20.4 25.9 19 25.5 C 17.5 25 17.2 22.3 18.1 19.3 C 18.9 16.7 20.5 14.9 21.8 14.8 Z M 29.7 14.9 C 31.6 14.9 33.9 17.1 35.2 20.3 C 36.8 23.9 36.5 27.5 34.6 28.4 C 32.7 29.2 29.8 26.9 28.3 23.2 C 26.7 19.6 27 16 28.9 15.1 C 29.2 15 29.5 15 29.7 14.9 Z M 49.3 28 L 48.6 29.4 C 44.2 37.2 38 43.8 31.3 46.3 C 27.9 47.5 24.5 47.7 21.1 46.5 C 17.8 45.2 14.6 42.6 11.7 38.2 L 11.2 37.3 L 12.2 37.4 C 31.3 39.8 38.2 33.4 47.9 28.7 L 49.3 28z" fill="rgba(255, 150, 0, 0.8)" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="0"></path></svn><div style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px">this.y =' + this.y + '<div>';
    return st;
  }
```